# Detect when application is closed

Tags: android, android-activity, detect

I want to know when the app is closed, because I need to erase a Database when the user shutdown the app, just in the moment when the user close the app is the right moment to erase the SQLite Database, how can I detect this?

Comment: **Read the docs:** http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: Yeah, i know this, but the question is, i need to know when the total application is closed, no when a activity is closed.

Comment: What you want is impossible. Your process may be terminated at any time, by the user or the OS, and you are not notified of this.

Comment: @CommonsWare You seem to be very aware of the Android Stack, is it a possibility to attach an Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks to the Application class and listen to onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) or any termination of the Application class itself? (just wondering)

Comment: @FeleMed: The `Application` is never terminated. The process just ends. The `onTerminate()` method is never called, nor is anything else.

Comment: You can try firebase on disconnect in the application https://stackoverflow.com/a/46711166/3904109

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Supposing you don't `finish()` your main activity, clearing your database inside the `onDestroy()` method of that activity might be the closest of what you want to accomplish. As has been pointed in the comments, refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle.

Comment: onDestroy() doesnt seem to work at times, android just skips executing the onDestry() method.

Comment: Using `onPause()` is encouraged, as `onDestroy()` execution is not 100% reliable (it pends on system resources)

Comment: But that would clear the DB on every device rotation

Comment: It does not make any sense because android allows multiple activity stack. Moreover, the user swipes the app out, onDestroy is not called

Answer (score 22):

This is a flawed design idea, which reflects a misunderstanding of the system - when the process overall dies, it's dead, meaning your code is no longer running.

You can do some tracking and have the last onDestory()'d activity do the cleanup as a courtesy, but don't assume that it will always actually happen (the method is not *always* called).  If having a stale copy is a problem, clean it up on the next run.

That said, you can try using the ndk to provide a handler for process termination signals, but still I wouldn't count on it working in all cases.  The limited potential to gain any sound functionality from this would probably not justify the effort unless you are already familiar with the concepts involved.

And do not for a minute mistake cleaning up for a security mechanism, as the file is there while your app is running, and would remain if your app terminated in an unexpected way.

Comment: "If having a stale copy is a problem, clean it up on the next run." - thanks, good suggestion

Answer (score 0):

In the last activity you could add this in the onBackPressed method:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    if(this is /*your activity*/ && isTaskRoot) {
        println("App closed by user")
    }
}
```