# Service: onTaskRemoved or onDestroy very rarely being called on swiping app off on the recent apps list

Tags: android

Service: `onTaskRemoved` or `onDestroy` very rarely being called on swiping app off on the recent apps list

How am I supposed to stop correctly for example video recording in this case? I just get corrupted (not playable) mp4 file

p.s. `android:stopWithTask="false"` is set of course (and it's default anyway)

Comment: i think you should bind you service to activity

Comment: @AhmedAbd-Elmeged on my activity `pause` or `stop` service should be still working (I'm not going to kill it at those event)

Comment: make this service run in the foreground - check `Service` API on how to do that

Comment: @pskink with foreground service `onTaskRemoved` will be called all the time on swiping app off?

Comment: @pskink I know how to do it, I make my service foreground when I start recording video (function of my app)...

Comment: @pskink I earlier swiped my app off when service was in foreground mode and also tried just now, methods `onTaskRemoved` or `onDestroy` are still not being called..

Comment: @pskink mb you didn't understand my question, I don't want to keep my service when I swipe my app off, I want to kill it and something before it's killed (stop correctly recording my video)

Comment: ok, so OS version are you testing on? on 4.4 `onTaskRemoved` is called with no problem

Comment: @pskink 6.0.1 Marshmallow

Comment: What happens if you don't set `stopWithTask`?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible in principle - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387774/detect-when-application-is-closed

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede default is `false` anyway, when I set `true` it never calls at all, with default false `onTaskRemoved` at least being called sometimes

Comment: you should set it `true` instead of false to stop the service

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have written an app specifically for testing this behavior.  I'd never tested it on my recently acquired Android 6 device, so I did just now.  The main activity starts the service in `onCreate` and stops it in `onBackPressed`.

On my LG-K450 (X Power) running 6.0.1, `onTaskRemoved` is called with 100% reliability.

If the service is running in the background, `onTaskRemoved` is called, but `onDestroy` is not, and the process is killed.  If `onStartCommand` returned `START_STICKY`, the service is restarted almost instantly.  (It used to take several seconds.)  Otherwise, it's restarted when I relaunch the main activity.

If the service is running in the foreground, `onTaskRemoved` is still called, but the service is *not* terminated.  This is new.  On older versions of Android, foreground services would be killed and restarted.

If you're not seeing calls to `onTaskRemoved`, my first suspicion would be a device-specific bug.  Let me guess... Samsung?

Comment: are you sure that you swipe specific app off? not just pressing X button to clear all apps from your recent apps list (with X button `onTaskRemoved` is being called ok for me, but with swipe for specific app isn't)

Comment: @user924 `onTaskRemoved` is called in either case -- all apps cleared or only my test app.  I noticed something new about foreground services; see my edit.