# Firebase update on disconnect

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

I have a node on firebase that lists all the players in the game. This list will update as and when new players join. And when the current user ( me ) disconnects, I would like to remove myself from the list.

As the list will change over time, at the moment I disconnect, I would like to update this list and update firebase.

This is the way I am thinking of doing it, but it doesn't work as .update doesnt accept a function. Only the object. But if I create the object beforehand, when .onDisconnect calls, it will not be the latest object... How should I go about doing this?

```
payload.onDisconnect().update( () => {
            const withoutMe = state.roomObj
            const index = withoutMe.players.indexOf( state.userObj.name )
            if ( index > -1 ) {
                withoutMe.players.splice( index, 1 )
            }
            return withoutMe
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onDisconnect` handler was made for this use-case. But it requires that the data of the write operation is known at the time that you set the `onDisconnect`. If you think about it, this should make sense: since the `onDisconnect` happens **after** your client is disconnected, the data of the data of that write operation must be known **before** the disconnect.

It sounds like you're building a so-called presence system: a list that contains a node for each user that is currently online. The [Firebase documentation has an example of such a presence system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-sample). The key difference from your approach is that it in the documentation each user only modifies their own node.

So: when the user comes online, they write a node for themselves. And then when they get disconnected, that node gets removed. Since all users write their node under the same parent, that parent will reflect the users that are online.

The actual implementation is a bit more involved since it deals with some edge cases too. So I recommend you check out the code in the documentation I linked, and use that as the basis for your own similar system.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Hmm... Because I'm trying to create a game room where users can join. And other users can see who's in the room. I guess it's similar to a chat room. The presence system that you linked, I'm not too sure how to use that in my case, unless there is a central server program that takes the presence and does something with the data by pushing and deleting from different rooms?

Comment: What you're describing is quite literally what a presence system is. The only difference with the one in the documentation is that in your case you want it to be per game room, which should be a fairly small modification. I recommend you try the one in the docs, and once it works make your modifications to it.

Comment: Your current approach simply can't work: after the user has disconnected, they cannot make changes anymore. That's why the change for each individual user must be known while they're connected, which the presence system in the docs ensures.

Comment: Thanks! I think I managed to modify the presence system you linked for this to work by having a central room state which lists players, then each user onDisconnect just pulls themselves from that state instead of caring about what's on the list.